# How to browse and Play local audio files on an iOS Device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file, audio

I am developing an iPhone app in which I need to provide the facility to the user where he/she will be able to select audio files saved on the device and will be able to play them in my application.Please give me right direction to proceed.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to use MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate for this.

```
  //in your .h file include the MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate
  //in your .m file
  - (IBAction) showMediaFilesPressed : (id) sender 
  {
     MPMediaPickerController *picker =
     [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

     picker.delegate                    = self;
     picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems  = NO;
     picker.prompt                      = NSLocalizedString(@"AddSongsPrompt", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");



     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];

     [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
     [picker release];

 }
```

This will give you the all the media files listed on your device. And to play those files you may write the code for that in its delegate method.

```
  - (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
  {
          //play your file here
  }
```

This article might help you more. http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mayur.Can I choose the file using MediaPicker and play it with AVAudioPlayer because I can't see any way using this method to get the path of the file I am going to play?

Comment: The case is such that I am using MPMOviePlayerController to play a video and wanted to play an audio file in the background.I managed to play some audio files present im my application bundle and now want to give the user facility to choose his own audio file from the device

Comment: okay.actually i dont knw much about AVAudioPlayer. However, you can play music with MPMediaPlayerContoller too. Check the article which i have posted at the end of the answer. It contains a demo project at the end.Download that..it'll help you to play the file in background with the help of MPMediaPickerController.

Comment: Yeah...you are right about MPMeadiaPlayerController but it is also true that if you are using MPMoviePlayerController to play the video then you can't use MPMediaPlayerContoller to play background music.It stops your video.i.e.they can't be used simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little but important aside: You will not be able to test run this code on the iOS simulator, since the simulator is not loaded with a media library.

The AddMusic sample project therefore has this statement in its project code:

```
#pragma mark Application setup____________________________

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#warning *** Simulator mode: iPod library access works only when running on a device.
#endif
```

Comment: Yes...got it while testing.Thanks for the reference. :)